# What are .in files?

Tags: compiling, make, configure, autoconf

Sometimes in the sources of projects I see "*.in" files. For example, a bunch of "Makefile.in"s. What are they for and/or what does the ".in" part mean? I assume that this has something to do with `autoconf` or `make` or something like those, but I'm not sure.

I've tried searching for ".in file extension", "autoconf .in file extension", "autoconf .in", "autoconf dot in", and other variants, with no luck.

Comment: If you want to know how autotools work, I suggest this series of articles: http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/gnu_coding_standards_applied_to_autotools.

Comment: I found this in my google search. Kinda scary. https://fileinfo.com/extension/in

Answer (score 29, accepted):

it's just a convention that signifies the given file is for `input`; in my experience, these files tend to be a sort of generic template from which a specific output file or script results.

Comment: Out of interest, could you cite some examples where ".in" is used in this way outside of the `autoconf` realm?

Comment: @spinkus Python packaging/dev tools use it now, e.g. `MANIFEST.in` and `requirements.in`. The former name would have been in use back in 2014 when you first asked!

Answer (score 37):

I believe the *automake* process involving a *Makefile.in* is something like this:

```
  Makefile.am
       |
      \'/
+--------------+
|   automake   |
+--------------+
       |
      \'/
   Makefile.in
       |
      \'/
+--------------+    +--------------+
| ./configure  |<-- |   autoconf   |<-- configure.in
+--------------+    +--------------+
       |
      \'/
    Makefile
```

Nobody actually writes a Makefile.in.  The only programmer-defined file here is the Makefile.am.

Comment: Well, on occasion I've written a `Makefile.in`, because automake wouldn't do what I want.

Answer (score 9):

They are input files for the `m4` macro preprocessor. Among other things, these files contain macros marked by @, that get expanded by m4.

Comment: Nope. `Makefile.in` is never touched by anything `m4` related.