# At sign after shebang?

Tags: scripting, perl, shebang

In [the Apache httpd project's "support/apxs.in" script](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/support/apxs.in), a text surrounded with `@` signs comes after `#!`. That is, the first line of the script is:

```
#!@perlbin@ -w
```

Is this a Perl thing or a UNIX kernel thing? In other words, it it possible to execute this script using `path/to/script/script_name.in`?

If not, then what is the reason to start the script with a `#!`?

Comment: those are [`.in` files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84380) (i.e. templates)

Comment: As a side note, `@` is fine in filenames so **if** you have an executable called `@perlbin@` which accepts the `-w` option and is able to interpret the contents of that file, then *yes* you can run that file.

Comment: @Bakuriu: "Valid", yes. "Fine"? Dubious.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This looks like a placeholder in an GNU Automake template which is going to be filled in by a `configure` script. So it's neither a Perl or Unix kernel thing, but a GNU autotools thing.

It is probably from a file in a source distribution, not from a file that was installed on the system through `make install` or a package manager.

Alternatively, it's from a broken build with GNU autotools that never defined `perlbin` properly.

That the file has a `.in` suffix confirms that it is supposed to be processed by `configure`.

No, you can not execute this file as it is. The placeholder will be replaced with the proper path to the `perl` executable when you run `configure`.

Comment: Yeah the link in the question leads to a source code repository.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You know what, I didn't even see that there was a link there.

Comment: Hehe I thought that may have been the case. I have suggested an edit that fixes a couple of problems with it, this being one of them :)

Comment: Seems like a problem with the styling of Unix.SE -- the link color isn't very distinct from the normal text color.

Comment: @Barmar It's not the first time I miss a link that's not explicitly advertised as a link.

Comment: [meta question about link color](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/make-link-colors-brighter-and-or-add-dotted-underline)